# Difference of two unboubded terms can be bounded?

Tags: real-analysis

So, if for a compact space $\mathcal{X}$ and $\forall a,b\in\mathcal{X}$, I have the following relationship

$f(a)-f(b)\leq L(a,b)$

here $L(a,b)$ is a bounded function of $a$ and $b$. Can we make a claim about the boundedness of $f(a)$ or $f(b)$.

Simply speaking, can the difference of two unbounded terms b bounded?

Thanks

Comment: With such a single-sided inequality, everything is possible.

Comment: But f appears on the LHS with plus AND minus… so it should be enough :-)

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f$ is unbounded w.l.o.g not bounded from above.
Then there exists $x_n \in X$ s.t. $$f(x_n) \nearrow +\infty$$

and for fixed $b\in X$ it holds $$f(x_n) - f(b) \le L(x_n,b)$$
But LHS tends to infinity so does RHS what's a contradiction.
Hence the assumption that $f$ is unbounded was wrong and f is bounded.